# undefined method "sortByColumns" in Custom Spark DataGrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I'm building a Flex application using some custom components, which I think is messing things up. I'm trying to `sortByColumn` in a spark data grid, using the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350020/setting-spark-datagrid-columns-default-sort-on-applications-creationcomplete) as a template. When I try to use the following in a function,

```
myGrid.sortByColumns(0,true);
```

I get the error:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method sortByColumns through a 
reference with static type com.components:MyReportGrid.
```

Anyone know how to remove this error? Is `MyReportGrid` somehow masking the correct location for the spark components? I also get "undefined method" errors when using some other functions, such as invalidateCell(), not sure if it's related or not to this error.

My data grid looks like:

```
...
<components:MyReportGrid id="myGrid" dataProvider="{_myData}"...>
    <components:columns>
        <fx:Array>
            <supportClasses:MyColumn ... />
            <supportClasses:MyColumn ... />
            <supportClasses:MyColumn ... />
            ...
```

where MyColumn is a class as follows:

```
import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;
public class MyColumn extends GridColumn
{
    ...
    public function MyColumn(headerText:String="header" width:Number=100 ...)
    {
       this.headerText=headerText;
       ...
    }
}
```

and MyReportGrid is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         width="400" height="300">
   import com.components.myClasses.MyColumn;
   import com.itemRenderers.myItemRenderer;
   import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
   import mx.collections.ArrayList;
   import mx.collections.ListCollectionView;
   import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;
   ...
   <s:DataGrid width="100%" ... />
</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will never work since your are calling `myGrid.sortByColumns(0,true);` on your `MyReportGrid` component which is of base type `Group`.

A `Group` does not have any method called `sortByColumns`

So you can either:

- Create a delegate method in your MyReportGrid component

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
   width="400" height="300">
    import com.components.myClasses.MyColumn;
    import com.itemRenderers.myItemRenderer;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.collections.ArrayList;
    import mx.collections.ListCollectionView;
    import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;
    ...

     <mx:Script>
       <![CDATA[
       public function sortByColumns(columnIndices:Vector.<int>, isInteractive:Boolean = false):Boolean{
           return internalGroupGrid.sortByColumns(columnIndices,isInteractive);
       }
       ]]>
     </mx:Script>

     <s:DataGrid width="100%" id="internalGroupGrid"... />
  </s:Group>
  ```
- Make DataGrid the root tag of your MyReportGrid component

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:DataGrid xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           width="400" height="300">
      import com.components.myClasses.MyColumn;
      import com.itemRenderers.myItemRenderer;
      import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
      import mx.collections.ArrayList;
      import mx.collections.ListCollectionView;
      import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;
      ...
  </s:DataGrid>
  ```

Comment: Should return type for sortByColumns in the first solution be `void`? Also, is `myGrid.sortByColumns(...);` a typo? Should it be just `sortByColumns(...);` in the first solution?

Comment: Changed the example for the return type. Anywhere in your appication where you embed your `MyReportGrid`, you should still be calling `myGrid.sortByColumns();` In this example, we are just creating a placeholder method that will "delegate" the call on `MyReportGrid` to the `DataGrid` it contains.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, it's kinda hard to give good response without seeing the code in it's full context, including build scripts and hierarchy. However, as far as I can tell, it seems like the compiler is missing information about what kind of object MyReportGrid is. Does it extend something that has that functionality or does it implement the function "sortByColumns"?

If you are looking for a way to get away from "type hinting" you can always do
    "myGrid["sortByColumns"](0, true)"

however, that is not recommended ;)

Btw, in your exaplanation, your were writing something about MyDataGrid which kinda had me lost for a while, until I realized it was a typo.

I'm pretty sure you have to make it obvious that your class "com.components:MyReportGrid" implements that function either directly or through extension.